# How to calculate rotation angle of closest pane in carousel

Tags: javascript

I have this carousel which rotates in 3D with the use of `-webkit-transform: rotateX(rotation in deg);`. It has 10 panes which means every 36deg there is a pane centered.

Now, I'm trying to create a "snap to" effect called on a `touchend` event, setting the closest pane centered flat in front.

My problem is, from an arbitrary rotation value, say -1820 deg, how do I calculate which pane, or rather, at what degree is the closest pane?

Hope that makes sense. A hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understod well your question, you should use the modulus operator, which is basically the division remainder, which according to [wg3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp) is defined as the percentage sign %.

Example: 
5%2 is equal to 1

In your case you could do semthing like

```
 var initialAngle= getAngle();  //let's say it's 1820 
 var closestPane= initialAngle%36; //which gives you 20.
```

So now you know the position of your angle resepct to the previous angle (let's call it A).
If you make an additional simple operation (36-20=16) you also know the distance from the following angle.

```
angle before ---- A ---- angle after
            20deg   16deg
```

Hope this helps

Comment: maybe your on to something there, but what I need is an angle which is at most +-36 from -1820.

Comment: to better understand the modulo operator, in case you need, I found this: 'modulo basically means "keep taking the second number away from the first number. When you can't do it any more without going into negative numbers, whatever's left is the answer"'. It was posted here http://ask.metafilter.com/43903/Help-me-understand-modulus-operators.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with based on Danele B's input..

```
function snapToAngle(Angle) {
var deltaAngle = Math.abs(Angle)%36; 

    if (Angle >= 0) { 
       (deltaAngle <= 18) ? Angle -= deltaAngle : Angle+=36-deltaAngle;
    } else {
       (deltaAngle <= 18) ? Angle += deltaAngle : Angle -= 36-deltaAngle;
    }
return Angle;
}
```

I'm sure there's a neater way of writing this, but it seems to work..